# cross platform git: possible strategies to handle platform specific files

Tags: java, eclipse, git, cross-platform

Using eclipse and (E)git for developing a java cross platform application (windows and linux) I wonder what is the best way of handling files that contain platform-specific elements. In for example `.classpath` the paths of the libraries differ and probably there will be more specific changes as well. When handling specific resources I presume that it is best to not add them to the index but maybe there are better strategies.

Any guidance on this point will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit** I do not agree with Alex Baranovski to put this question on hold. What I ask for is guidance. That is not always clear-cut, but as Alex Baranovski has a strategy to cope with this problem, others will have strategies as well. I (and probably others) might learn from that. I have changed the title: I did ask for the best strategy, I now ask for possible strategies and, as I could not change the title anymore: argued strategies.

Answer (score 1):

This question should be put on hold, because practice has it preachers and opponents.

In company I'm working for we have made **separate repository** for system-configs. Each branch of it's repo is like "Windows_7_64" and "Ubuntu_32" etc. In repo of application we **git-ignored** the config files.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your company's strategy. +1